# count unique lists in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of lists, and I would like to find a way to return a dataframe with the lists in one column and the total counts in another. My problem is finding a way to add together list that contain the same values, for example I want to find the total of ['a', 'b'] and ['b', 'a'] in the end.

So for example the dataframe:

```
Lists          Count
['a','b']        2
['a','c']        4
['b','a']        3
```

would return:

```
Lists          Count
['a','b']        5
['a','c']        4
```

Comment: Huh?  How do you get a count of 4 for ['a', 'c'].

Comment: @Alexander sorry for the confusion, I'm looking at the count in the "Count" column - so since ['a','c'] is unique, the count stays 4. ['a','b'] and ['b','a'] would be 2 + 3 in the 'count' column; that's what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use sets (after coercing them to strings).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Lists': [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a']], 
                   'Value': [2, 4, 3]})

df['Sets'] = df.Lists.apply(set).astype(str)

>>> df.groupby(df.Sets).Value.sum()
Sets
set(['a', 'b'])    5
set(['a', 'c'])    4
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

list are unhashable. so, sort and convert to tuple,

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
   count   lists
0      2  [a, b]
1      4  [a, c]
2      3  [b, a]

In [82]: df['lists'] = df['lists'].map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))

In [83]: df
Out[83]: 
   count   lists
0      2  (a, b)
1      4  (a, c)
2      3  (a, b)

In [76]: df.groupby('lists').sum()
Out[76]: 
    count
lists        
(a, b)      5
(a, c)      4
```